# Best practices for expposing a Azure VM to Internet

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm, azure-security

We need to expose one of our Azure VMs located in a VNet to Internet. We are using F5 ADC for all inbound traffic both to on-premise and to Azure.
What is the best practice to expose an Azure VM to Internet if you have zero-trust approach in mind?

Appreciate all kinds of advice

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to expose Azure VM to the Internet considering Zero Trust strategy, you should check:

- Workloads are monitored and alerted to abnormal behavior.
- Every workload is assigned an app identity—and configured and deployed consistently.
- Human access to resources requires Just-In-Time.

After above items are completed, check next:

- Unauthorized deployments are blocked, and alert is triggered.
- Granular visibility and access control are available across workloads.
- User and resource access segmented for each workload.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/zero-trust/infrastructure
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/zero-trust/

Answer (score 1):

It depends what on the VM you want to expose to the Internet.

If it is a web site running on the VM you could use a web appication firewall https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/ag-overview

If it is RDP access to the VM you could use Azure Bastion
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-bastion/